# Disable "evil sharing" option in scribd embed widget?

Tags: pdf, embed, scribd

The Scribd widget includes a sharing option with evil counters / no 2-click solution for the user.

Is there a way to disable it?

```
<iframe class="scribd_iframe_embed" src="//www.scribd.com/embeds/16315444/content?start_page=1&view_mode=scroll&access_key=key-a4skwjdi4bxgkek0u0c&show_recommendations=false" data-auto-height="false" data-aspect-ratio="0.75" scrolling="no" id="doc_51513" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/UU6VH/

Answer (score 0):

in order for you to remove the sharing options. You need to configure the file you upload on scribd into Private. Doing that it will hide the share and embed options on viewer. Hope it help.